# Auto Email in Access when closed

Tags: database, email, ms-access

I'm a relatively new to Microsoft Access and I want to set up an auto-emailing function on a database to send all newly logged queries. I've found the code for auto sending an email but my question is:

Will an auto email function send even when the database is closed or is it reliant on it being open? If published to the web will this make a difference

EDIT: it'll need to go to multiple addresses as well

Thanks

Luke

Comment: What is the code you have for sending emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the procedure when the db is closed, will have to call the procedure from an external script. I use VBScript. Example:

```
Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase "C:\Users\Owner\June\LL\Umpires.accdb"
accessApp.Run "SendEmails"
accessApp.Quit
```

Use Notepad to create the script file with a .vbs extension.

Then I use Windows TaskManager to call the script.

I expect publishing to web will have an impact but no idea how.